# segfault when assigning an std::thread to a vector<std::thread>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, segmentation-fault

This segfaults:

```
std::vector<std::thread>    _pool;
State &                     _state;

...

for(uint32_t n = 0; n < nThreads; ++n)
    _pool[n]  = std::thread(_thFunction, std::ref(_state));
```

This does not:

```
std::vector<std::thread>    _pool;
State &                     _state;

...

for(uint32_t n = 0; n < nThreads; ++n)
    _pool.push_back( std::thread(_thFunction, std::ref(_state)) );
```

The difference in the use of push_back to the vector instead of using assignment to a specific entry in the vector.

_thFunction is an std::function.

When I apply a pool.reserve(10) to the first block of code, I still get a segfault on the first assignment.

I suspect that this is related to move semantics, but I'm not sure.  What's going on here?

A stacktrace from gdb seems to indicate a null this pointer:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004092e5 in std::thread::joinable (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/thread:162
162     { return !(_M_id == id()); }
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000004092e5 in std::thread::joinable (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/thread:162
#1  0x000000000040927a in std::thread::operator=(std::thread&&) (this=0x0, 
    __t=<unknown type in /home/stackuser/src/dsl/build/debug/server/dsl, CU 0x0, DIE 0x37b88>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/thread:150
#2  0x000000000041350d in ThreadPool<std::function<void (State&)> >::ThreadPool(State&, unsigned int, std::function<void (State&)>) (this=0x69aed0, state=..., nThreads=2, thFunction=...)
    at src/server/ThreadPool.h:38
#3  0x0000000000408405 in Application::Application (this=0x6946e0) at src/server/Application.cpp:69
#4  0x0000000000455594 in Singleton<Application>::CreateInstance () at src/server/Singleton.h:12
#5  0x0000000000454997 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdc98) at src/server/main.cpp:85
```

Comment: Reserving does **NOT** give you space that's available for use!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector::reserve` will only "prepare" the vector to grow, but the logical size of the vector is still 0. `So _pool[n]  = ...` is still invalid. You should use `std::vector:resize` instead.

Comment: confirmed; this works.  always get reserve and resize mixed up!  thanks!

Comment: It's pretty easy: reserve just reserves space for elements to be added later. `resize` changes the size, i.e. changes the number of elements

Comment: The curious thing is that you would think that there is a pointer in the vector element which holds the current array. reserve would increase the size of this pointer right? So you shouldn't get segfault unless the vector object is explicit throwing segfault when using the [] operator outside the logical size.

Comment: @bofjas: That's a naive view. You likely won't get a segfault reading from that "array", sure, but as soon as you try to perform operations on the elements in that array that have never even been constructed, then those operations are likely to fail. In this case, the internals of `std::thread` (the assignment operator) think they are operating on an instance of `std::thread` but said instance is non-existent. This is plainly evident from the OP's stack trace, where a member function receives a NULL `this` pointer and then attempts to dereference it!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So vector is using malloc and not new[]? If std::vector used new[] then wouldn't that call the default constructor for std::thread?

Comment: @bofjas: `reserve` does _not_ construct any elements. It's as simple as that. How that is achieved internally is besides the point.

Comment: @bofjas: vector uses `Allocator::allocate` where `Allocator` is a template parameter and defaults to `std::allocator<T>` where `T` is the value type template parameter. `std::allocator<T>` in turn uses the placement allocation: `void* operator new[]( std::size_t count, void* ptr );`

Comment: @bofjas, The last sentence in my comment may be incorrect, but I can't edit anymore :( I would double check the standard if I needed to know, but I usually don't need such details anyway :P

Answer (score 3):

Read reference [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) of the `operator[]` that you're using.

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.

So, when you call `_pool[n]` on an empty vector, you get a reference to a non-existing object and undefined behaviour ensues. Assigning a value to this reference does not grow the vector.

`reserve` does not add any elements to the vector either. It simply increases the *capacity* of the vector which means that inserting elements to the end won't invalidate iterators / references / pointers to elements until that capacity is reached.

`resize(n)` would create `n` objects in the vector which I suspect you are expecting `reserve` to do and it's excellent way to initialize the vector with identical objects when you don't know the count and the value at the time the vector is constructed. But if you were to overwrite the objects anyway, `push_back` with `reserve` would waste less resources. Or, if you know the values that you want in the vector, you could simply fill the vector using the constructor.

Comment: I'd said that "When I apply a pool.reserve(10) to the first block of code, I still get a segfault on the first assignment." won't this make a difference?

Comment: No. I'll add details to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with move semantics, you're simply trying to assign to elements of a vector that don't exist.

`_pool.push_back()` creates a new element, but `_pool[n]` does not.

`reserve()` does not create elements either, it just allocates memory for them (but does not construct them)

Either `resize` the vector so the elements exist before you assign to them, or use `push_back`

Comment: I'd said that "When I apply a pool.reserve(10) to the first block of code, I still get a segfault on the first assignment."  won't this make a difference?

Comment: **`reserve()` does not create elements either**

Comment: yeah, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reserve()` does not create any elements - it only makes sure that when you do create them, no allocation will be performed. Create the vector with 10 empty elements like that:

```
std::vector<std::thread>    _pool(10);
```

and your first example will work